# How to only allow access to a webpage if it is coming from a post request from swift application?

Tags: php, swift

I have created a website that connects to a database that is sql. I am using apple's programing language "swift" to retrieve the data using php and http post requests. When accessing this file via a web browser you can view all of the data. It is returning all the rows in a table. I am worried someone will use this file to connect to my database for "hacking" or sql injection of sorts. Even if they cannot use it for malicious purposes I still wouldn't want them to be able to view the file. How would I only allow access to this file if it is coming from a post request from a swift app? If there is no direct solution to this, is there any ideas or suggestions that could put me in the right track on finding some form of protection from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must lock down access to the web data using some sort of authentication. It doesn't matter if it comes from a Swift app. What matters is that you can verify that it is coming from YOUR app.

Make sure that you are using SSL. If you don't then you will be easily hacked.

Implement an authentication mechanism like a basic auth, or some sort of token.